# Jackson @JsonIgnoreProperties targeting nested attributes

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is there a way to make @JsonIgnoreProperties target nested attributes?

Something like the code below:

```
public class ParentObject() {
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "subAttributeA.subAttributeB.subAttributeC" })
    private ChildObject attribute;
}
```

In this example, I want that **subAttributeC** is not included in the serialization of a **ParentObject** - but this same **subAttributeC** still need to be serializable in other scenarios.

If not possible with annotations, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is to use `@JsonSerialize` with a custom serializer. This operates on a low abstraction level and you basically have to specify how to serialize every single attribute. There's an example [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization) that uses a flat object, but given that `JsonGenerator` has methods like `writeObject` etc., I'm sure this can be used for a hierarchical structure, too.

Answer (score -1):

If jackson is configured to not serialize null attributes:

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

Then a simpler workaround is to set the unwanted attribute as null before returning it.