# Java Jackson Serialization ignore specific nested properties with Annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

I'm using jackson (with spring boot) to return some DTOs like json. The problem is that I have specific DTO which contains nested objects, which contains another objects. Can I have ignore some nested properties directly from the DTO, without any Annottations on the nested objects (because they are used in another DTOs)

```
public class MyDTO {

  private MyObjectA a;

}

public class MyObjectA a {

  private MyNestedObject b;

}
```

I want when i serialize MyDTO to exclude  **MyNestedObject b**
I've tried with @JsonIgnoreProperties, but it not works with nested objects.
Can I achieve this mission only with Annotations in the MyDTO class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51452202/jackson-jsonignoreproperties-targeting-nested-attributes

Comment: My question is not exactly the same. I'm asking how if it is possible to achieve this only with annotations.

Comment: Your question is actually a special case of the one I've pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `@JsonView`. You need to annotate some *nested objects* but it is not kind a static thing that then hides everything from other DTOs or so.

For example you could declare following views to use:

```
public class View {
    public static class AllButMyNestedObject {
    }
    public static class AlsoMyNestedObject 
        extends AllButMyNestedObject {
    }    
}
```

Then annotating your classes like:

```
@JsonView(AllButMyNestedObject.class)
public class MyDTO {
    private MyObjectA a;
}
```

and

```
public class MyObjectA {
    @JsonView(AlsoMyNestedObject.class)
    private MyNestedObject b;
}
```

you can decide with mapper what to serialize, like:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String result = mapper
    .writerWithView(View.AlsoMyNestedObject.class)
// OR .writerWithView(View.AllButNestedObject.class)
    .writeValueAsString(myDto);
```